# Install XConnect 9 without license file

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

I would like to install XConnect 9 using SIF without license file. This would, for example, allow me to build a XConnect Docker image and provide the required Sitecore license at runtime.

By default the SIF however starts the XConnect service/jobs and these check for a valid license file.

Any thoughts on how to achieve a license less install?

Comment: Have you tried passing a dummy license.xml file?

Comment: A dummy license.xml does not work for XConnect (due to the fact that it start the processes, and these check for a valid license).

Comment: Dummy license does *only* not work because the maengine requires it when installing it as service. Workaround is to manually install the maengine service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove Parameter "LicenseFile" on line 19 from the standard xconnect-xp1-collection.json. Then modify the tasks by removing "SetLicense" at line 316, "startAppPool" at line 451, and also "StartWebsite" at line 459.

My xconnect-xp1-collection.json

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
//         Sitecore Install Framework - XConnect XP1 Collection               //
//                                                                            //
//  Run this configuration to install the XConnect Collection service.        //
//                                                                            //
//  NOTE: Only single line comments are accepted in configurations.           //
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

{
    "Parameters": {
        // Parameters are values that may be passed when Install-SitecoreConfiguration is called.
        // Parameters must declare a Type and may declare a DefaultValue and Description.
        // Parameters with no DefaultValue are required when Install-SitecoreConfiguration is called.

        "Package": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The path to the Web Deploy package to deploy."
        },
        "SiteName": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "XConnectCollection",
            "Description": "The name of the site to be deployed."
        },
        "SSLCert": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The certificate to use for HTTPS web bindings. Provide the name or the thumbprint. If not provided a certificate will be generated.",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        },
        "XConnectCert": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The certificate to use for encryption. Provide the name or the thumbprint."
        },
        "SqlDbPrefix": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The prefix used for all Sql databases."
        },
        "SqlAdminUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "sa",
            "Description": "The Sql admin user account to use when installing databases."
        },
        "SqlAdminPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "12345",
            "Description": "The Sql admin password to use when installing databases."
        },
        "SqlCollectionUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "collectionuser",
            "Description": "The Sql admin user account to use when installing databases."
        },
        "SqlCollectionPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "Test12345",
            "Description": "The Sql admin password to use when installing databases."
        },
        "SqlProcessingPoolsUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "poolsuser",
            "Description": "The Sql user for the Processing Pools connection string in Sitecore."
        },
        "SqlProcessingPoolsPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "Test12345",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Processing Pools connection string in Sitecore."
        },
        "SqlMarketingAutomationUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "marketingautomationuser",
            "Description": "The Sql user for the Marketing Automation connection string in Sitecore."
        },
        "SqlMarketingAutomationPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "Test12345",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Marketing Automation connection string in Sitecore."
        },
        "SqlMessagingUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "messaginguser",
            "Description": "The Sql user for the Messaging connection string in Sitecore."
        },
        "SqlMessagingPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "Test12345",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Messaging connection string in Sitecore."
        },
        "SqlServer": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": ".\\SQLSERVER",
            "Description": "The Sql Server where databases will be installed."
        },
        "XConnectEnvironment": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "Development",
            "Description": "The configuration environment for this instance."
        },
        "XConnectLogLevel": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "Information",
            "Description": "The level of log information to output."
        },
        "InstallDirectory": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "D:\\",
            "Description": "The path for the package to deploy to."
        }
    },
    "Variables": {
        // Variables are values calculated in a configuration.
        // They can reference Parameters, other Variables, and config functions.

        // The prefix for shards created by the tool
        "Sharding.Database.Prefix": "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_Xdb.Collection.Shard')]",

        // The database names.
        "Sql.Database.ShardMapManager":     "[concat(variable('Sharding.Database.Prefix'), 'MapManager')]",
        "Sql.Database.Shard0":              "[concat(variable('Sharding.Database.Prefix'), '0')]",
        "Sql.Database.Shard1":              "[concat(variable('Sharding.Database.Prefix'), '1')]",
        "Sql.Database.Pools":               "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_Processing.Pools')]",
        "Sql.Database.MarketingAutomation": "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_MarketingAutomation')]",
        "Sql.Database.Messaging": "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_Messaging')]",

        // The security certificate details
        "Security.CertificateStore": "Cert:\\Localmachine\\My",
        "Security.SSL.CertificateThumbprint": "[GetCertificateThumbprint(parameter('SSLCert'), variable('Security.CertificateStore'))]",
        "Security.XConnect.CertificateThumbprint": "[GetCertificateThumbprint(parameter('XConnectCert'), variable('Security.CertificateStore'))]",
        "Security.XConnect.CertificatePath":        "[joinpath(variable('Security.CertificateStore'), variable('Security.XConnect.CertificateThumbprint'))]",

        // The sites full path on disk
        "Site.PhysicalPath": "[joinpath(parameter('InstallDirectory'), parameter('SiteName'))]",

        // The sites data folder
        "Site.DataFolder": "[joinpath(variable('Site.PhysicalPath'), 'App_Data')]",

        // The path to the automation engine windows service
        "Services.IndexWorker.InstallPath": "[joinpath(variable('Site.DataFolder'), 'jobs','continuous','IndexWorker')]",
        "Services.IndexWorker.Name": "[concat(parameter('SiteName'), '-indexworker')]",

        // The sharding tool details.
        "Sharding.Root.Path":       "[joinpath(variable('Site.DataFolder'), 'collectiondeployment')]",
        "Sharding.Tool.Path":       "[joinpath(variable('Sharding.Root.Path'), 'Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe')]",
        "Sharding.DacPac.Path":     "[joinpath(variable('Sharding.Root.Path'), 'Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.Sql.dacpac')]",
        "Sharding.Map.Names":       ["ContactIdShardMap", "DeviceProfileIdShardMap", "ContactIdentifiersIndexShardMap" ],
        "Sharding.DB.Connection":   "[sqlconnectionstring(parameter('SqlServer'), '', parameter('SqlAdminUser'), parameter('SqlAdminPassword'))]",
        "Sharding.Edition":         "Basic",
        "Sharding.SqlCmd.Path.CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLogin":   "[joinpath(variable('Sharding.Root.Path'), 'CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLogin.sql')]",
        "Sharding.SqlCmd.Path.CreateShardManagerApplicationDatabaseUser":   "[joinpath(variable('Sharding.Root.Path'), 'CreateShardManagerApplicationDatabaseUser.sql')]",
        "Sharding.SqlCmd.Path.CreateShardApplicationDatabaseUser":          "[joinpath(variable('Sharding.Root.Path'), 'CreateShardApplicationDatabaseUser.sql')]"

    },
    "Tasks": {
        // Tasks are separate units of work in a configuration.
        // Each task is an action that will be completed when Install-SitecoreConfiguration is called.
        // By default, tasks are applied in the order they are declared.
        // Tasks may reference Parameters, Variables, and config functions.

        "CreatePaths": {
            // Ensure the destination path for the site exists.
            "Type": "EnsurePath",
            "Params": {
                "Exists": [ "[variable('Site.PhysicalPath')]" ]
            }
        },
        "CreateAppPool": {
            // Creates or updates the app pool.
            "Type": "AppPool",
            "Params": {
                "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Properties": {
                    "ProcessModel": {
                        "identityType" : "ApplicationPoolIdentity"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions": {
            // Set permissions for the App Pool User to access the client certificate.
            "Type": "FilePermissions",
            "Params": {
                "Path" : "[ResolveCertificatePath(variable('Security.XConnect.CertificatePath'))]",
                "Rights": [
                    {
                        "User": "[concat('IIS AppPool\\', parameter('SiteName'))]",
                        "FileSystemRights": ["Read"],
                        "InheritanceFlags": [ "None"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "CreateWebsite": {
            // Creates or updates the IIS website instance.
            "Type": "Website",
            "Params": {
                "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "ApplicationPool": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "PhysicalPath": "[variable('Site.PhysicalPath')]"
            }
        },
        "StopWebsite": {
            // Stops the website if it is running.
            "Type": "ManageWebsite",
            "Params": {
                "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Action": "Stop"
            }
        },
        "StopAppPool": {
            // Stops the app pool if it is running.
            "Type": "ManageAppPool",
            "Params": {
                "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Action": "Stop"
            }
        },
        "RemoveDefaultBinding": {
            // Removes the default *:80 web binding
            "Type": "WebBinding",
            "Params": {
                "SiteName" : "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Remove" : [ { "Port": "80", "IPAddress": "*" } ]
            }
        },
        "CreateBindingsWithThumprint": {
            // Configures the site bindings for the website.
            "Type": "WebBinding",
            "Params": {
                "SiteName" : "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Add": [
                    {
                        "HostHeader": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                        "Protocol": "https",
                        "SSLFlags": 1,
                        "Thumbprint": "[variable('Security.SSL.CertificateThumbprint')]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Skip": "[not(parameter('SSLCert'))]"
        },
        "SetClientCertificatePermissions": {
            "Type": "WebsiteClientCert",
            "Params": {
                "SiteName": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Setting": "Accept"
            }
        },
        "SupportListManagerLargeUpload":{
            "Type": "IISConfiguration",
            "Params": {
                "SiteName": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "ConfigPath": "system.webServer/serverRuntime",
                "Key": "uploadReadAheadSize",
                "Value": 491520000
            }
        },
        "CreateHostHeader": {
            // Sets a hostheader for the website.
            "Type": "HostHeader",
            "Params": {
                "HostName": "[parameter('SiteName')]"
            }
        },
        "SetPermissions": {
            // Sets permissions for the app pool user.
            "Type": "FilePermissions",
            "Params": {
                "Path" : "[variable('Site.PhysicalPath')]",
                "Rights": [
                    {
                        "User": "[concat('IIS AppPool\\', parameter('SiteName'))]",
                        "FileSystemRights": "FullControl",
                        "InheritanceFlags": [ "ContainerInherit", "ObjectInherit"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "InstallWDP": {
            // Syncs the web deploy package with the website.
            "Type": "WebDeploy",
            "Params" : {
                "Verb": "Sync",
                "Arguments": {
                    "Source": { "Package": "[resolvepath(parameter('Package'))]" },
                    "Dest": "Auto",
                    "SetParam":  [
                        { "Name": "IIS Web Application Name", "Value":  "[parameter('SiteName')]" },
                        { "Name": "Database Server Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlServer')]" },
                        { "Name": "Database Admin User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlAdminUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Database Admin User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlAdminPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Collection Database Server Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlServer')]" },
                        { "Name": "Collection Shard Map Manager Database Name", "Value":  "[variable('Sql.Database.ShardMapManager')]" },
                        { "Name": "Collection Shard 0 Database Name", "Value":  "[variable('Sql.Database.Shard0')]" },
                        { "Name": "Collection Shard 1 Database Name", "Value":  "[variable('Sql.Database.Shard1')]" },
                        { "Name": "Processing Pools Database Name", "Value":  "[variable('Sql.Database.Pools')]" },
                        { "Name": "Marketing Automation Database Name", "Value":  "[variable('Sql.Database.MarketingAutomation')]" },
                        { "Name": "Messaging Database Name", "Value":  "[variable('Sql.Database.Messaging')]" },
                        { "Name": "Collection Database Application User Name", "Value":  "[parameter('SqlCollectionUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Collection Database Application User Password", "Value":  "[parameter('SqlCollectionPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Processing Pool Database Application User Name", "Value":  "[parameter('SqlProcessingPoolsUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Processing Pool Database Application User Password", "Value":  "[parameter('SqlProcessingPoolsPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Marketing Automation Database Application User Name", "Value":  "[parameter('SqlMarketingAutomationUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Marketing Automation Database Application User Password", "Value":  "[parameter('SqlMarketingAutomationPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Messaging Database Application User Name", "Value":  "[parameter('SqlMessagingUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Messaging Database Application User Password", "Value":  "[parameter('SqlMessagingPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "XConnect Server Configuration Environment", "Value":  "[parameter('XConnectEnvironment')]" },
                        { "Name": "XConnect Server Configuration Environment", "Value":  "[parameter('XConnectEnvironment')]" },
                        { "Name": "XConnect Server Certificate Validation Thumbprint", "Value":  "[variable('Security.XConnect.CertificateThumbprint')]" },
                        { "Name": "XConnect Server Log Level", "Value":  "[parameter('XConnectLogLevel')]" }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "CreateBindingsWithDevelopmentThumprint": {
            // Creates a new thumprint with a custom CA
            "Type": "AddWebFeatureSSL",
            "Params": {
                "HostName": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "OutputDirectory": "[variable('Site.DataFolder')]"
            },
            "Skip": "[parameter('SSLCert')]"
        },
        "CleanShards" : {
            // Drop existing shards.
            "Type": "Command",
            "Params": {
                "Path": "[variable('Sharding.Tool.Path')]",
                "Arguments":[
                    "/operation", "drop",
                    "/connectionstring", "[variable('Sharding.DB.Connection')]",
                    "/dbedition", "[variable('Sharding.Edition')]",
                    "/shardMapManagerDatabaseName", "[variable('Sql.Database.ShardMapManager')]",
                    "/shardMapNames", "[join(variable('Sharding.Map.Names'))]"
                ],
                "TaskName" : "ShardingTool - Clean"
            }
        },
        "CreateShards": {
            // Create new shards.
            "Type": "Command",
            "Params": {
                "Path": "[variable('Sharding.Tool.Path')]",
                "Arguments":[
                    "/operation", "create",
                    "/connectionstring", "[variable('Sharding.DB.Connection')]",
                    "/dbedition", "[variable('Sharding.Edition')]",
                    "/shardMapManagerDatabaseName", "[variable('Sql.Database.ShardMapManager')]",
                    "/shardMapNames", "[join(variable('Sharding.Map.Names'))]",
                    "/shardnumber", 2,
                    "/shardnameprefix", "[variable('Sharding.Database.Prefix')]",
                    "/shardnamesuffix", "\"\"",
                    "/dacpac", "[variable('Sharding.DacPac.Path')]"
                ],
                "TaskName" : "ShardingTool - Create"
            }
        },
        // Create Collection Shard Database Server Login
        "CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLoginSqlCmd": {
            "Type": "Command",
            "Params": {
                "Path": "sqlcmd",
                "Arguments": [
                    "-i",
                    "[variable('Sharding.SqlCmd.Path.CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLogin')]",
                    "-S",
                    "[parameter('SqlServer')]",
                    "-U",
                    "[parameter('SqlAdminUser')]",
                    "-P",
                    "[parameter('SqlAdminPassword')]",
                    "-v",
                    "[concat('UserName=',parameter('SqlCollectionUser'))]",
                    "-v",
                    "[concat('Password=',parameter('SqlCollectionPassword'))]"
                ]
            }
        },
        // Create Collection Shard Manager Database User
        "CreateShardManagerApplicationDatabaseUserSqlCmd": {
            "Type": "Command",
            "Params": {
                "Path": "sqlcmd",
                "Arguments": [
                    "-i",
                    "[variable('Sharding.SqlCmd.Path.CreateShardManagerApplicationDatabaseUser')]",
                    "-S",
                    "[parameter('SqlServer')]",
                    "-U",
                    "[parameter('SqlAdminUser')]",
                    "-P",
                    "[parameter('SqlAdminPassword')]",
                    "-v",
                    "[concat('UserName=',parameter('SqlCollectionUser'))]",
                    "-v",
                    "[concat('ShardMapManagerDatabaseName=',variable('Sql.Database.ShardMapManager'))]"
                ]
            }
        },
        // Create Collection Shard 0 Database User
        "CreateShard0ApplicationDatabaseUserSqlCmd": {
            "Type": "Command",
            "Params": {
                "Path": "sqlcmd",
                "Arguments": [
                    "-i",
                    "[variable('Sharding.SqlCmd.Path.CreateShardApplicationDatabaseUser')]",
                    "-S",
                    "[parameter('SqlServer')]",
                    "-U",
                    "[parameter('SqlAdminUser')]",
                    "-P",
                    "[parameter('SqlAdminPassword')]",
                    "-v",
                    "[concat('UserName=',parameter('SqlCollectionUser'))]",
                    "-v",
                    "[concat('ShardDatabaseName=',variable('Sql.Database.Shard0'))]"
                ]
            }
        },
        // Create Collection Shard 1 Database User
        "CreateShard1ApplicationDatabaseUserSqlCmd": {
            "Type": "Command",
            "Params": {
                "Path": "sqlcmd",
                "Arguments": [
                    "-i",
                    "[variable('Sharding.SqlCmd.Path.CreateShardApplicationDatabaseUser')]",
                    "-S",
                    "[parameter('SqlServer')]",
                    "-U",
                    "[parameter('SqlAdminUser')]",
                    "-P",
                    "[parameter('SqlAdminPassword')]",
                    "-v",
                    "[concat('UserName=',parameter('SqlCollectionUser'))]",
                    "-v",
                    "[concat('ShardDatabaseName=',variable('Sql.Database.Shard1'))]"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Powershell looks like this to run with SIF and was able to have an XConnect install with db deployment without any errors.

```
$PSScriptRoot = "C:\Sitecore 9 Install"
$SqlAdminUser = "sitecore"
$SqlAdminPassword = "sitecore" 
$XCC_Cert_Name = "$prefix.xconnect_client"
$XCRD_Cert_Name = "$prefix.xconnectsearch_client"
$XCMA_Cert_Name = "$prefix.xReferenceData_client"
$XCMAR_Cert_Name = "$prefix.xAutomationOperations_client"
$SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr/"
$prefix = "sitecoreTEST"
$SqlServer = "(local)\SQLDEV12"
$InstallDirectory = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\THROW AWAY"
$Environment = "Production"
$SolrRoot = "C:\Program Files\solr-6.6.2"
$SolrService = "SOLR 662"

#install client certificate for xconnect servers
$certParams = 
@{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"
    XCC_CertificateName = $XCC_Cert_Name
    XCRD_CertificateName = $XCRD_Cert_Name
    XCMA_CertificateName = $XCMA_Cert_Name
    XCMAR_CertificateName = $XCMAR_Cert_Name
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose


# deploy xconnect instance 
$xconnectParamsCollection = 
@{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp1-collection-v2.json"
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 (OnPrem)_xp1collection.scwdp.zip"
    #LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"
    Sitename = $prefix + "XCC.sentry.com"
    SqlDbPrefix = "SitecoreTEST"
    SqlServer = $SqlServer 
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser 
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword 
    XConnectCert = $XCC_Cert_Name
    XConnectEnvironment = $Environment
    InstallDirectory = $InstallDirectory
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParamsCollection
```

You'll need to manually start the AppPool and Website once you do place your license but everything should be bound correctly from IIS. Hope this helps.